# How to remove badge in Sencha Touch 2.3

Tags: sencha-touch, badge

How can I dynamically remove a badge from a tab bar that I previously set with `setBadgetText('text')`?

Official documentation doesn't mention a solution and if I try with `setBadgeText('')` or `setBadgeText()` I can see a right margin near the tab button - so I deduce it's not the right way.

Is there something like `removeBadge()`?

Comment: this is strange... in 2.3.1 setBadgeText('') properly removes it for me. What theme are you using? All good for me with cupertino (apple) theme.

Comment: Yes, the badge disappears but a right margin remains near the tab button.